# Seeing if text in cell contains same text in different cell

Tags: vba, excel

i have a table in Excel and i would like to create a macro where it checks if the text in all the cells Column B and C are present in the cells in Column A, and then remove the matching words from Column A. Example: The macro will see that A1 has red and blue in its text, so does B1 and C1. It will then remove the text in A1 that matches with B1 C1. The macro will then repeat for A2, B2, C2, and A3, B3, C3.

When i tried that with my code, it would just erase everything

```
       A           B      C 
1  redbluegreen | blue | red
2  greypinkblack| pink | grey
3  yellowpurple |purple| yellow
```

Here's my code:

```
Sub Sort()

Dim A As String
Dim B As String
Dim C As String
Dim Result As String

Columns(1).Value = A
Columns(2).Value = B
Columns(3).Value = C

If A.contains(B) Or A.contains(C) Then
    Result = InStr(1, B ,"")
    A = Result
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: So you want to remove all duplicates from columns A to C?  Does it matter which columns the duplicates are in? (ie, all in 1 column, 1 in each column, etc?)  What should happen with the remainders?  Leave them as is? Should you show an example of your data as it is, and what it should look like?  What about partial matches? Is this homework?  Why do you need to do this? Did you try Googling this?    You can't really just make up commands and expect Excel to do what you're thinking...

Comment: I want to remove the duplicate only on column A. The remainders are left alone. I did some research, but i couldn't find anything close to what i want to achieve

Comment: if that's the closest you could get, I think you need to try a *little* bit harder.  There are *thousands* of sites out there for learning the very basics of coding (this site is for programmers so share a *specific& problem with their (otherwise functioning) code. (Sorry but not a single line of your code makes sense.)  Here's a suggested starting search related to your goal:  Figure out how to copy and paste a cell programmatically (with code).   (So Google "Excel VBA copy paste cell")

Comment: Copying and Pasting a cell programmatically is not really what i wanted

Comment: Can you add a column of the expected output?

Comment: ...also some of the other clarifications I asked for would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Sort()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        cell.Value= Replace(Replace(cell.Text, cell.Offset(,1).Text, "") , cell.Offset(,2).Text, "")
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what you did? I see that you declared cell as a Range, then you made a loop that selects the cells in Range. I just dont quite understand what you did inside the loop

Comment: each cell content is being updated by eliminating any occurrence of the content of the adjacent cells (see [VBA Replace function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/replace-function))

Comment: glad to hear it.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand, you don't need VBA. `SUBSTITUTE()` does the trick:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A2,C2,""),B2,"")
```

[image]